How to show alert or popup in a user event script?
I am doing item line amount validation. I want to restrict user from saving the invoice record if user adds negative amount on any of the item amount line.
Is there any way to show alerts or popups using server side script?
I will appreciate the help!

No, creating an alert or pop-up means interacting with the browser - which is client side.  You could use a client script validateLine() event function to check as each line is added, or check them all at once in a (client script) saveRecord() function.  Either approach would allow you to use the browser's native window.alert() or use one of the NetSuite N/ui/dialog or N/ui/message modules.

Yes correct. Can we do line level validation using workflow? Error message should be dynamic with item  and line number.

You should use a client script for that
